# How do I use a variable defined in an 'if' statement?

Tags: variables, if-statement, conditional-statements, scope

```
public class Help
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        if (index = 1)
        {
            String greeting = "hello";
        }
        else
        {
            String greeting = "goodbye";
        }
    }

    callAMethod(greeting);
}
```

When I define the String within the if statement I get a 'cannot find symbol' error. How can I get around this and still be able to create a string depending upon an above condition?

Comment: Where is index coming from? It's not being defined anywhere.

Comment: @Cold - How can you tell it is Java?

Comment: @Ash the declaration for the main function.  A C# main function is capitalized, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I know this isnt in the origional question but if its a string array, how could I do that if I dont know the dimensions of the array in advance?

Comment: @Jayden Check out using an ArrayList of Generics to accomplish that.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    String greeting;
    if( index == 1){
       greeting = "hello";
    }else{
       greeting = "goodbye";
    }
 }

 callAMethod(greeting);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare it outside the scope -

```
String greeting = "goodbye";
if( index == 1)
{
    greeting = "hello";
}

callAMethod(greeting);
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable outside of the `if` block.

Right before the `if` statement, you can say `String greeting = "";`

Then, inside the `if` and `else` blocks, you say `greeting = "hello";` and so on.

So you have separated declaring the variable from assigning the value to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the greeting variable before the statement:

```
String greeting;

if (index == 1) {
   greeting = "hello";
} else {
   greeting = "bye";
}

System.out.println(greeting);
```

Comment: I know this isnt in the origional question but if its a string array, how could I do that if I dont know the dimensions of the array in advance?

Comment: You could define an int (call it counter) the same way I did for that String. Then after the if/else or the loop, you can do something like String[] array = new String[counter]